# Is there a way to detect a classes constness inside of itself?

Tags: c++, c++17, constants, constexpr

Consider the following example and output:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct X {

bool is_const = std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>;

constexpr bool isConst1() const {
    return is_const;
}

constexpr bool isConst2() const {
    return std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>;
} 

};

int main() {
    X a;
    const X b;
    std::cout << "X is const (1): " << a.isConst1() << '\n';
    std::cout << "X is const (2): " << a.isConst2() << '\n';
    std::cout << "const X is const (1): " << b.isConst1() << '\n';
    std::cout << "const X is const (2): " << b.isConst2() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

```
X is const (1): 0
X is const (2): 1
const X is const (1): 0
const X is const (2): 1
```

Apparently, regardless of whether a type is actually const or not, the constness of `this` always depends on the compile-time context and is not determined at runtime or implicitly templated.

Is there some other way to detect the constness of class from inside it? If so, this would simplify code related to iterators, among other things.

I know that for this to work, all `const` functions would have to be implicitly templated for `const`/non-`const` instantiations. So this is probably not possible.

**EDIT:**
The original example falsely used `std::is_const_v<decltype(*this)>` and always returned `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do

```
constexpr bool isConst() const {
    return std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7LNdhR)

your issue is that `decltype(this)` is `/*const*/ X&` (not `/*const*/ X`)

Another issue is that you need 2 versions (the one for non-const object):

```
constexpr bool isConst() {
    return std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K78BW4)

There is [proposal p0847r0](http://open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html)

which would allow:

```
template <typename Self>
constexpr bool is_const_with_proposal(Self&& this self)
{
    return std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<Self>>;
}
```

Comment: I tried that (see edited question) but the constness of the variable still has no impact on the result.

Comment: As your member are `const`, `*this` is const reference. you have to have 2 methods currently.

Comment: With those two methods, it actually is possible to distinguish constness at runtime. Unfortunately that wouldn't work in a constexpr context, which is what I wanted to achieve ideally. (So as to make if-constexpr decisions based on the constness, etc.)

I approved the answer anyways because it's the only one which provides some degree of solution.

Comment: As you might noticed is Demo, you might use it in constexpr context (by adjusting return type)

Comment: `X const x;` cannot determine that the object is (will be?) `const` within the constructor, correct?

Comment: constructor is indeed special and not `const` (even if it would be construct const object).

Comment: How are your two `isConst` functions different from `return true;` and `return false;` respectively?

Comment: @J.Schultke: You can’t possibly use something like this in a constexpr if condition: those always have one value (per instantiation), and you would want both here.

Comment: @DavisHerring: I don't succeed to test for non-constness in constant exprression context without that [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ud4jyS).

Comment: @Jarod42: It’s true that using `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` allows “calling” the member function on a non-constant object (avoiding the strange question of whether a member function call on such an object is a constant expression), but the `decltype(this)` is plainly not buying anything.

Answer (score 3):

`*this` returns a reference (to `const` or non-`const`), so `std::is_const_v<decltype(*this)>` is checking the const-ness on the reference; but reference can't be `const` itself and the result is always `false`. [References [dcl.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1)

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers
>   are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef],
>   [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case
>   the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

I think you want to check the const-ness on the object (being referenced); you can add `std::remove_reference` as

```
return std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>>;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6j3SXHrqTdVW5H1x)

Comment: I tried that (see edited question) but the constness of the variable still has no impact on the result.

Comment: @J.Schultke Yes, in `const` member function you'll always get the result `true`, otherwise you'll get result `false`; even the object being called on is non-`const` you'll get the same result. As you said *it depends on the compile-time context*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. const-qualified methods can be invoked even on non--const-qualified object without any problem. Checking `decltype(this)` type does not help at all since it does not consider type of the object this method getting invoked on, only type of the implicit `this` argument.

Comment: Not even the constexpr evaluator can help you here; it could detect the UB from an assignment through `const_cast`, but you can’t modify preexisting objects in a constant expression anyway.